# A method for calculating the frequency of digits

Tags: java

I've written a class that finds the total of an integer by adding up the two digits. For example the digit totals of `0, 5, 12, 213, 999 and 1111` are
`0, 5, 3, 6, 27 and 4 respectively. I need to write a method:

`public static double digitTotalFrequency(int max, int digitTotal)`

This method should `return` the proportion of numbers which have the given `digitTotal` of all numbers in the range 0, 1...max. Eg the `digitTotalFrequency(9, 3)` is `0.1` since only one number out of the first 10 numbers has a digit total of 3. Also, `digitTotalFrequency(99,3)` is `0.04` (since out of the first 100 numbers only the numbers 3, 12, 21, and 30 have a digitTotal of 30). I am struggling to do this, help please, thank you.

```
public static double digitTotalFrequency(int max, int digitTotal){ 
    int number = max; 
     while (number>0) { 
       digitTotal = digitTotal + (number%10); 
       number = number/10; 
     } 
  return digitTotal/max; 
}
```

Comment: Break down the task into smaller sub-tasks, and try to solve each one, one at a time. Then if still stuck, come back with your code and your much more specific question.

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you show what have you tried? Which errors you got? Also please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can give you a better help. Help us to help you :)

Comment: Hi there, yes the problem is that I don't know where to start, shall I use a while loop for example, sorry if I should have had already had some code written, thank you

Answer (score 0):

you need to divide up your task into two parts

1. keeping a running count of the digit total for all the numbers in range 0 to max.
2. keeping count of digit total for each individual number in range 0 to max.

for instance, the digit total of 12 and 21 is going to be the same. so you need to store this information somewhere in order to use it again. this will reduce the amount of work that you do.

this is know as dynamic programming or memoization.

try to think about this a little bit. if you struggle, i can get you started with some code

**EDIT: Program Code**

try to read through this and see exactly what is going on

```
public class Jnk {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(digitTotalFrequency(99,3));
    }

    public static double digitTotalFrequency(int max, int digitTotal){ 

        HashMap<String,Integer> counts = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

        counts.put("0", 0);
        counts.put("1", 1);
        counts.put("2", 2);
        counts.put("3", 3);
        counts.put("4", 4);
        counts.put("5", 5);
        counts.put("6", 6);
        counts.put("7", 7);
        counts.put("8", 8);
        counts.put("9", 9);

        int [] runs = new int[1];

        if(max<=10)
            return (double)digitTotal/max;

        else
            getTotal(0,max,counts,runs,digitTotal);

        return (double)runs[0]/max; 
    }

    private static void getTotal(int currentNumber, int max, HashMap<String, Integer> counts,int [] runs, int target) {


        if(currentNumber==max)
            return;

        String key = getKey(currentNumber);

        if(counts.containsKey(key))
        {
            int total = counts.get(key);

            if (total==target)
            {
                System.out.println("Found "+currentNumber);
                runs[0] += 1;
            }
            getTotal(currentNumber+1,max,counts,runs,target);
        }
        else
        {   
            int total = getDigitCount(currentNumber);

            counts.put(key, total);

            if (total==target)
            {
                System.out.println("Found "+currentNumber);
                runs[0] += 1;
            }
            getTotal(currentNumber+1,max,counts,runs,target);
        }
    }

    private static Integer getDigitCount(int currentNumber) {

        int digitTotal = 0;
        while (currentNumber>0) { 
               digitTotal = digitTotal + (currentNumber%10); 
               currentNumber = currentNumber/10; 
             } 

        return digitTotal;
    }

    private static String getKey(int min) {

        String number = String.valueOf(min);

        char[] numberArray = number.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(numberArray);
        String key = String.valueOf(numberArray);

        return key;
    } 
}
```

Comment: thats great thank you, will get back to you in a bit!